# Sveltekit: Importing ESM package produces errors that works with vite

Tags: svelte, es6-modules, commonjs, arcgis-js-api, sveltekit

I am trying to get [Esri ArcGis's NPM package](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/es-modules/) to work with SvelteKit.

The `@arcgis/core` is supposed to be ESM per the linked documentation. However, when I try to import it into SvelteKit [as shown here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/install-and-set-up/#es-modules-via-npm) I get an error about CommonJS. In a new SvelteKit app change `index.svelte` to

```
<script>
 import Map from "@arcgis/core/Map";
 import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";

 const map = new Map({
   basemap: "arcgis-topographic" // Basemap layer service
 });
</script>
```

Will produce the error

> Named export 'setAssetPath' not found. The requested module '@esri/calcite-components/dist/components/index.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports. CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

```
import pkg from '@esri/calcite-components/dist/components/index.js';
const {setAssetPath: o} = pkg;
```

[Sandbox demonstrating error here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sveltekit-sandbox-forked-kjhkzs?file=/src/app.html).

First off, I thought this issue had to do with Vite. So I imported `@arcgis/core` in vite as [this tutorial](https://odoe.net/blog/vite-jsapi) shows. It works fine.

If I go and look at `@esri/calcite-components/package.json`, which `@arcgis/core` imports, I see that `@esri/calcite-components/package.json` does not have `"type": "module"` set. It appears that `@arcgis/core` is importing a CommonJS module.

When I tried to debug further I realized `calcite-components` is a Stencil project which does include ESM though the error claims the package is CommonJS. Either way, the error itself had a recommended fix. When I go into the problem file and apply the fix:

`node_modules/@arcgis/core/widgets/support/componentsUtils.js`

```
// import{setAssetPath as o}from"@esri/calcite-components/dist/components/index.js" Old import statement
import pkg from '@esri/calcite-components/dist/components/index.js';
const {setAssetPath: o} = pkg;
```

it fixes the issue. Then a new one is created, which I believe is different, in the file `node_modules/@arcgis/core/widgets/support/chartUtils.js`:

The first line of that file is:

```
import{chartColorSets as t}from"@esri/calcite-colors";
```

With the error

> The requested module '@esri/calcite-colors' does not provide an export named 'chartColorSets'.

This is strange to me because `calcite-colors` is ESM and does have named exports. If I remove all the imports from `@arcgis/core` and just copy / paste `import{chartColorSets as t}from"@esri/calcite-colors"` into my `index.svelte` it works fine.

Why does a Vite project work just fine and why does SvelteKit report `calcite-colors` does not have a named export only when it is imported via `@arcgis/core` and not via my `index.svelte`?

Others have [had this issue on the esri forums](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-javascript-questions/svelte-kit-build-error/m-p/1123928)

Comment: What version of nodejs are you running?

Comment: @jfriend00 16.14.2

Comment: So, that package is poorly or inaccurately documented.  I tried following their directions exactly from scratch and it simply does not work as they say it should.  You need to go find where you can get support and see what they say.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for taking the time to do that. I will contact them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dynamic imports inside the onMount block

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(async () => {
        const Map = (await import('@arcgis/core/Map')).default;
        const MapView = (await import('@arcgis/core/views/MapView')).default;

        const map = new Map({
            basemap: 'gray-vector'
        });

        const view = new MapView({
            container: 'viewDiv',
            map: map
        });

        view.when(() => {
            console.debug('Map loaded');
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="viewDiv" />

<style>
    @import '@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/light/main.css';
    
    #viewDiv {
        min-height: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that I have seen which works so far. Thank you! Does importing via onMount remove the tree shaking? https://kit.svelte.dev/faq makes it appear that it does. Do you think `@arcgis` can be used as a normal import if the commonJS imports are removed from the `@arcgis` package, or is this the permanent solution?